# XQuery Replace Value With Conditional Failing

Tags: xquery, basex, xquery-update

i am in the middle of creating xquery replace-value of node action in `XQuery`.

But seems this code is not working therefore the `IF-ELSE` statement is always going to else.

This is my code:

```
declare function local:replacing($contextData as element()) 
as element()*
{    
    copy $pipeline := $contextData/Handler/Data/*

     modify(

   if(not(empty(data($pipeline/Payload/sample/transactionType)))) then 
     replace value of node $pipeline/Payload/sample/transactionType with 'XXX' else (),
   if(not(empty(data($pipeline/Payload/sample/revision)))) then
     replace value of node $pipeline/Payload/sample/revision with 'XXX' else ()

      )
 return $pipeline
 };
```

I try against this sample XML but the result is always not `XXX` when the field `revision` is having value. (this always goes to `else` statement)

```
let $result :=
<root>
<Handler>
  <Data>
    <root>

      <Payload>
            <sample>
            <transactionType></transactionType>
            <revision>123</revision>
            <board>1</board>
            <mission>1</mission>
            <method>Manual</method>
            <listOfBoard>
              <board>
                <type>small</type>
                <amount>5054</amount>
                <token>300</token>
              </board>
            </listOfBoard>
            <pricing>300</pricing>
            <playing>Wed</playing>
          </sample>   
    </Payload>

    </root>

  </Data>
</Handler>
</root>
```

**Current Result:**

```
<root>
  <Payload>
    <sample>
      <transactionType/>
      <revision>123</revision>
      <board>1</board>
      <mission>1</mission>
      <method>Manual</method>
      <listOfBoard>
        <board>
          <type>small</type>
          <amount>5054</amount>
          <token>300</token>
        </board>
      </listOfBoard>
      <pricing>300</pricing>
      <playing>Wed</playing>
    </sample>
  </Payload>
</root>
```

**Expected Result**

```
<root>
      <Payload>
        <sample>
          <transactionType/>
          <revision>XXX</revision>
          <board>1</board>
          <mission>1</mission>
          <method>Manual</method>
          <listOfBoard>
            <board>
              <type>small</type>
              <amount>5054</amount>
              <token>300</token>
            </board>
          </listOfBoard>
          <pricing>300</pricing>
          <playing>Wed</playing>
        </sample>
      </Payload>
    </root>
```

Any ideas for this?

*Update*

As recommended by Har below, i change the code into:

```
 if(not(empty(data($pipeline/Payload/sample/transactionType)))) then 
             replace value of node $pipeline/Payload/sample/transactionType with 'XXX'
         else (
            if(not(empty(data($pipeline/Payload/sample/revision)))) then
            replace value of node $pipeline/Payload/sample/revision with 'XXX' else ()
         )
```

But seems the result is the same. It still goes to else () statement.
Any ideas?

Thank you before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, `empty()` checks for empty sequence, so sequence containing one empty string is considered `true` by `empty()`. You can just pass `data()` result to `if` since empty has Effective Boolean Value of `false` :

```
if(data($pipeline/Payload/sample/transactionType)) then 
    replace value of node $pipeline/Payload/sample/transactionType with 'XXX' else (),
if(data($pipeline/Payload/sample/revision)) then
    replace value of node $pipeline/Payload/sample/revision with 'XXX' else ()
```

Comment: thanks for your update. But seems that this IF-Else logic still getting me the same result. Only else block is return. I made changes to first `replace value of node` by removing else () since it is giving me an error in the baseX.

Any ideas? I will update the question.

Comment: Can you post sample XML that should go to `if` block? Your current XML rightly go to `else` since it has empty `transactionType`, while the `if` evaluates to `true` when `transactionType` is not empty, right?

Comment: Hi har, thanks for your comments. Seems the logic which i need to update is not one by another. It should be parallel. So in my expected result it is: `if the value is none`, then show as `none`. Else `if there is a value` just show `'XXX'`. Is it possible to update two of field simultaneously?

Comment: I see, I completely misunderstood the problem. In this case, your initial XQuery is closer to solution than mine. The problem was, `empty()` checks for empty sequence, so sequence containing one empty string is considered `true` by `empty()`

Comment: wow, thanks for your generous help. I already try your solution. But seems still getting the same result, Har. The  `<revision>` still goes to `else()` statement, in addition if i put a value inside `<transactionType>` it is also executed the `else()` part. Seems this xquery cannot change it.

i use baseX 8.3 by the way.